# Search DataFrame column for words in list

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, nlp, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a new DataFrame column that contains words that match between a list of keywords and strings in a df column...

```
data = {
'Sandwich Opinions':['Roast beef is overrated','Toasted bread is always best','Hot sandwiches are better than cold']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

keywords = ['bread', 'bologna', 'toast', 'sandwich']

df['Matches'] = [df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in df['Sandwich iOpinions'].str.split() if i in keywords]), axis=1)
```

This seems like it should do the job but it's getting stuck in endless processing.

Comment: can you please post your expected output?

Comment: I would want a new df column that contains any matches between the 'opinions' column and the list of keywords. Blank or null if there are no matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for kw in keywords:
    df[kw] = np.where(df['Sandwich Opinions'].str.contains(kw), 1, 0)

def add_contain_row(row):
    contains = []
    for kw in keywords:
        if row[kw] == 1:
            contains.append(kw)
    return contains

df['contains'] = df.apply(add_contain_row, axis=1)

# if you want to drop the temp columns
df.drop(columns=keywords, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Warning: make sure `'Sandwich Opinions'` and `'contains'` are not in `keywords` before using this code!

Answer (score 0):

Create a regex pattern from your list of words:

```
import re

pattern = fr"\b({'|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in keywords)})\b"
df['contains'] = df['Sandwich Opinions'].str.extract(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                     Sandwich Opinions contains
0              Roast beef is overrated      NaN
1         Toasted bread is always best    bread
2  Hot sandwiches are better than cold      NaN
```